# OpenGL glUseProgram fails (error 1282 - INVALID_OPERATION)

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2

Before I start. My shader program linked successfully, and all of the linked units
compiled successfully.

So, I have a OpenGL program, with SDL2's implementation set to use the core profile with GL version 4.0

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 0);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
//...
mSimWindow.makeGLContext();      //inlines : mOpenGL = SDL_GL_CreateContext(mWindow);
mSimWindow.makeContextCurrent(); //inlines : SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(mWindow, mOpenGL);
```

There are no errors at this point.

I'm using the monolithic varriaty of shader program. I have two classes to deal with this,
Shader and ShaderProgram, where the former is only used by the later.

ShaderProgram's constructor accepts two file paths, for a vertex shader and a fragment shader.

Here's the relevant code from these classes;

```
bool
Shader::compile()
{
    if (mType == Type::Undefined)
        return false;

    mShader = glCreateShader(static_cast<GLenum>(mType));

    const GLchar * src = mRaw.c_str();
    glShaderSource(mShader, 1, &src, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(mShader);

    GLint success = 0;
    glGetShaderiv(mShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

    if (success!=0)
    {
        //... some error handling
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool
ShaderProgram::link()
{
    mProgram = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(mProgram, mVertexShader->shaderID());
    glAttachShader(mProgram, mFragmentShader->shaderID());  

    glLinkProgram(mProgram);
    glDetachShader(mProgram, mVertexShader->shaderID());
    glDetachShader(mProgram, mFragmentShader->shaderID());

    GLint isLinked;
    glGetProgramiv(mProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, (int *)&isLinked);

    return (isLinked==0) ? true : false;        
}
```

The above is used like this

```
Graphics::ShaderProgram sp(".\\Shaders\\vertex.vert",
        ".\\Shaders\\fragment.frag");   

//...
glClearColor(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1);
while (!(mSimState == SimulationState::Quiting))
{
    SDL_PumpEvents();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    sp.use();
    mesh.use();
    //TwDraw();
    mSimWindow.glSwap();
}
```

Finally,

```
void 
ShaderProgram::use()
{
    glUseProgram(mProgram);
    auto e = glGetError();
}
```

e ends up being 1282 (INVALID_OPERATION)

If at any point before glUseProgram(..) I call glGetError() it returns 0. So the problem is somehow in relation to that call. A quirk I don't really understand is if I feed the program some geometry
it will somehow manage to actually render it, just not using my shader.

Example. 
[image]

I'm rather confused, any help or advice would be appreciated.

---

edit:

As a follow up. For some reason I thought 0 was true, *sigh*. Using GL_TRUE(1) caused my error handling code to actually show me the error.

I made the same mistake as this guy when reading the shader: [glsl shader compilation issue at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024433/glsl-shader-compilation-issue-at-runtime)

std::getline doesn't insert a newline character, so the source was being read in as a single line; which of course isn't valid.

Comment: Did you check the results of `Shader::compile()` and `Shader::link()`? Make sure your shaders are actually being compiled and linked correctly.

Comment: `if (success!=0)` you should rather check for `success != GL_TRUE`. Same for `return (isLinked==0) ? true : false;`.

Comment: I wish it was just that. Yes, true in both cases.

Comment: Wait - okay, GL_TRUE is defined as 1? I think I'm seeing the issue here...

Comment: Okay - well, this is embarrassing. But yes, I mixed up in my mind what true and false were in terms of 0 and 1, 0 is false, any non-zero value is true. I'm being simple... Okay, that's fixed and its giving me some lovely error messages now. *sigh* - well. That was a 5 hour experience wondering why seemingly correct code wasn't working.

Comment: @tkausl - thanks; it was that. Any idea on why its managing to draw something without a shader set though? I didn't think that was possible with the core profile?