# OpenGL shader loading fails

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I'm having a problem with my shader loading code.  The bizarre thing that's confusing me is that it works maybe once in 5 times, but then only sort of works.  For instance, it'll load the frag shader, but then texturing won't work properly (it'll draw a strange semblance of the texture over the geometry instead).  I think the problem is with the loading code, so that's what my question is about.  Can anyone spot an error I haven't found in the code below?

```
char* vs, * fs;

vertexShaderHandle   = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
fragmentShaderHandle = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

long sizeOfVShaderFile = getSizeOfFile(VERTEX_SHADER_FILE_NAME);
long sizeOfFShaderFile = getSizeOfFile(FRAGMENT_SHADER_FILE_NAME);

if(sizeOfVShaderFile == -1)
{
    cerr << VERTEX_SHADER_FILE_NAME<<" is null!  Exiting..." << endl;
    return;
}
if(sizeOfFShaderFile == -1)
{
    cerr << FRAGMENT_SHADER_FILE_NAME<<" is null!  Exiting..." << endl;
    return;
}

vs = readFile(VERTEX_SHADER_FILE_NAME);
fs = readFile(FRAGMENT_SHADER_FILE_NAME);

const char* vv = vs, *ff = fs;

glShaderSource(vertexShaderHandle  , 1, &vv, NULL);

cout << "DEBUGGING SHADERS" << endl;
cout << "VERTEX SHADER:  ";
printShaderInfoLog(vertexShaderHandle);
cout << endl;

glShaderSource(fragmentShaderHandle, 1, &ff, NULL);

cout << "FRAGMENT SHADER:  ";
printShaderInfoLog(fragmentShaderHandle);
cout << endl;


glCompileShader(vertexShaderHandle);

cout << "VERTEX SHADER:  ";
printShaderInfoLog(vertexShaderHandle);
cout << endl;

glCompileShader(fragmentShaderHandle);

cout << "FRAGMENT SHADER:  ";
printShaderInfoLog(fragmentShaderHandle);
cout << endl;


programHandle = glCreateProgram();

cout << "DEBUGGING PROGRAM" << endl;

glAttachShader(programHandle, vertexShaderHandle);

printProgramInfoLog(programHandle);

glAttachShader(programHandle, fragmentShaderHandle);

printProgramInfoLog(programHandle);


glLinkProgram(programHandle);

printProgramInfoLog(programHandle);

glUseProgram(programHandle);

printProgramInfoLog(programHandle);


delete[] vs; delete[] fs;
```

Here's the readFile function:

```
char* readFile(const char* path)
{
    unsigned int fileSize = getSizeOfFile(path);

    char* file_data = new char[fileSize];

    ifstream input_stream;

    input_stream.open(path, ios::binary);

    input_stream.read(file_data, fileSize);

    input_stream.close();
    //this is deleted at the end of the shader code
    return file_data;
}
```

All of the below messages are from the exact same executable (no rebuild).

Here's the first possible error message:

```
BallGLWidget::initializeGL called
DEBUGGING SHADERS
VERTEX SHADER:  
FRAGMENT SHADER:  
VERTEX SHADER:  ERROR: 0:17: '<' : syntax error syntax error


FRAGMENT SHADER:  
DEBUGGING PROGRAM
ERROR: One or more attached shaders not successfully compiled

ERROR: One or more attached shaders not successfully compiled

glGetError enum value:  GL_NO_ERROR
```

Another possible error message:

```
BallGLWidget::initializeGL called
DEBUGGING SHADERS
VERTEX SHADER:  
FRAGMENT SHADER:  
VERTEX SHADER:  ERROR: 0:17: 'tt' : syntax error syntax error


FRAGMENT SHADER:  ERROR: 0:33: '?' : syntax error syntax error


DEBUGGING PROGRAM
ERROR: One or more attached shaders not successfully compiled

ERROR: One or more attached shaders not successfully compiled
```

Here's the output when it works (maybe 1 in 5 or 6 times)

```
BallGLWidget::initializeGL called
DEBUGGING SHADERS
VERTEX SHADER:  
FRAGMENT SHADER:  
VERTEX SHADER:  
FRAGMENT SHADER:  
DEBUGGING PROGRAM
Image format is GL_RGB
Checking textures...
glGetError enum value:  GL_NO_ERROR
```

I seriously doubt its the shaders themselves since they do work sometimes... and the reported errors are garbage.

If any more information would be helpful I'll gladly provide it.

EDIT:  Here's the shaders

The vertex shader:

```
attribute vec2 a_v_position;
attribute vec2 a_tex_position;

varying   vec2 tex_coord_output;


void main()
{
    tex_coord_output = a_tex_position;

    gl_Position = vec4(a_v_position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

The fragment shader:

```
varying vec2 tex_coord_output;

uniform sampler2D ballsampler;


void main()
{
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(ballsampler, tex_coord_output);
}
```

Comment: Could we take a look at the actual shaders?

Comment: Sure, I posted them in an edit

Comment: Can you check the return value of the ifstream.read() calls to make sure that the data you are reading is the actual data and that it's not failing for some reason? Your initialization seems correct at a glance and the errors seem to indicate it may be reading trash data from the streams (will double check your code just in case im wrong in this assumption)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading the files but as far as I can see you are not zero-terminating the text. Try allocating filesize+1 and set the last char to zero.

Comment: Thanks!  That was it!  Great, I would have never thought of that.

Comment: Either zero terminate, or supply the glShaderSource with the length of the data.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a duplicate of [Getting garbage chars when reading GLSL files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344640/getting-garbage-chars-when-reading-glsl-files/7345355#7345355) and here's my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7345355/524368) to it:

---

You're using C++, so I suggest you leverage that. Instead of reading into a self allocated char array I suggest you read into a std::string:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

std::string loadFileToString(char const * const fname)
{
    std::ifstream ifile(fname);
    std::string filetext;

    while( ifile.good() ) {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(ifile, line);
        filetext.append(line + "\n");
    }

    return filetext;
}
```

That automatically takes care of all memory allocation and proper delimiting -- the keyword is RAII: Resource Allocation Is Initialization. Later on you can upload the shader source with something like

```
void glcppShaderSource(GLuint shader, std::string const &shader_string)
{
    GLchar const *shader_source = shader_string.c_str();
    GLint const shader_length = shader_string.size();

    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &shader_source, &shader_length);
}

void load_shader(GLuint shaderobject, char * const shadersourcefilename)
{
    glcppShaderSource(shaderobject, loadFileToString(shadersourcefilename));
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much for the code snippets! Saved me a chunk of work!